# Overriding dynamically created dag's attributes (start_date)

Tags: python, airflow

Say I had a `dag1.py` file:

```py
@dag(
   dag_id="my_dag",
   start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 9, 28, tz="UTC"),
   catchup=True
   # ...
)
def some_dag_code(name="bob", age=21):
   @task()
   def print_name(name):
      print(name)
   
   @task()
   def print_age(age):
      print(age)
   
   task1 = print_name(name)
   task2 = print_age(age)

dag = some_dag_code(name="bob", age=21)
```

I can then re-use the logic in a `dag2.py` file by doing the following:

```py
from dags.dag1 import some_dag_code

dag = some_dag_code(name="michael", age=31)

dag.dag_id = "my_dag_but_for_michael"  # this works

dag.start_date = pendulum.datetime(2023, 3, 5, tz="UTC")  # does nothing (uses 28-sep)
# dag.catchup = False  # this works
```

Any ideas how I can override the `start_date`?

Answer (score 0):

There are different options for dynamically creating DAGs. The one that is probably simplest to use with the example you gave is wrapping the DAG creation into its own function and passing the DAG parameters you want to override to that function:

```py
import pendulum

from airflow.decorators import dag, task


def create_dag(dag_id, start_date, schedule, name, age):
    @dag(dag_id=dag_id, start_date=start_date, schedule=schedule, catchup=False)
    def some_dag_code(name, age):
        @task()
        def print_name(name):
            print(name)

        @task()
        def print_age(age):
            print(age)

        task1 = print_name(name)
        task2 = print_age(age)

    my_dag = some_dag_code(name=name, age=age)

    return my_dag


dag_1 = create_dag(
    "dag_1", start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None, name="bob", age=21
)
dag_2 = create_dag(
    "my_dag_for_michael", start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 2, 2), schedule=None, name="michael", age=31
)
```

There are some examples for other methods, like creating DAGs from a JSON in [this guide](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dynamically-generating-dags). Hope this helps :)